# Connecting to Bing API

Tags: r, api, bing-api

I am looking to use Bing API to extract data in R. When I am using the following query in my browser

```
https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/Web?Query=%27analytics%27&$format=json
```

I am getting the search results in json format. But I have to enter the UserID (Blank) and password (authorization token) for authorization first. 
How can I merge the query with the authorization token in R so that I can directly load the search results in my R environment?

Comment: Is this supposed to be a POST statement? You can add a body, see https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/httr.pdf

Answer (score 1):

You can use authenticate function as a part of httr package:

```r
library(httr)

response = GET(url = 'https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/Web?Query=%27analytics%27&$format=json', 
           authenticate('','auth token', type = 'basic'))
res = content(response, encoding = 'json')
```